# Timestamp with timezone to pandas datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How can I cast this type of object(text):

```
2019-12-15 19:14:16+01:00
```

in pandas [datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) or [Timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) object?

When I do `.replace('+01:00','')` nothing happens and when I do `pd.datetime(df.timestampcolumn)` or `pd.Timestamp(df.timestampcolumn)` it gives error.

`.replace(u'+01:00','')` doesn't work either when I target for Unicode chars.

My column looks like this:

```
0        2019-12-15 19:14:16+01:00
1        2019-12-15 19:11:24+01:00
2        2019-12-15 15:59:35+01:00
3        2019-12-15 15:41:51+01:00
4        2019-12-15 15:41:51+01:00
```

Comment: Pass utc=True to pd.to_datetime

Comment: What error do you receive? `pd.Timestamp('2019-12-15 19:14:16+01:00')` works for me.

Comment: @QuangHoang TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>  when I try to put utc=True

Comment: @Arn It must be some char that I'm unable to detect than...can figure out what...

Comment: Try: `df.timestampcolumn.apply(pd.Timestamp)`

Comment: Or `from dateutil.parser import parse; df.timestampcolumn.apply(parse)` and please provide traceback

Comment: @Arn it didn't throw error but when I check dtypes it's still object...weird.

Comment: Could you add the whole problematic column to the question?

Comment: When I type df.dtypes should I see Timestamp as type of object or is it just object. Because if it's just object I guess it works..

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df.timestampcolumn, utc=True)` doesn't work for you? Where did that `int` come from?

Comment: @QuangHoang I don't know why is throwing about that int when it's clearly seeing it as object. See full error here: https://pastebin.com/i61QytY2

Comment: @Arn is this ok: https://pastebin.com/6U4CxARm if yes. Why is not saying that its Timestamp object?

Comment: @Arn it seems like df.timestampcolumn.apply(pd.Timestamp) runs ok. I'm just wondering why is it not listing it as Timestamp object. Can you put it in answer so I can accept.

Comment: In pandas all other objects are `object` :-). Not sure about your pandas version. `to_datetime` runs on my computer.

Comment: @QuangHoang it should I guess. I don't know why it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the `pd.Timestamp` function directly on on the column with `pd.Series.apply`:

```
df.timestampcolumn.apply(pd.Timestamp)
```